# Algorithm logic for filling packages with items of different dimensions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, logic

I'm writing some shipping functionality for an application I am working on. One of the requirements is finding the most efficient way of determining what items can fit into a box. We also have a requirement that only two items can be placed in any one box at a time and they have to fit the box exactly with no space left over.

We will simplify the problem by assuming that the sizes of boxes and items are integers (instead of actual dimensions).

I need to write a function that takes an array of item sizes, and the box size, as parameters and check to see if any two items can fit into the box perfectly.

For example, assume we want to see if 2 items will exactly fill a box with size 4.
2 items with sizes 1 & 2 will not work because there is 1 unit of free space in the box.

Thus the input {Item Sizes: [1,2], target: 4} would return false

Example Input and Output:

```
input: {Item Sizes: [1,3,5], target: 2} output: false
input: {Item Sizes: [1,1,3,5], target: 2} output: true
input: {Item Sizes: [1,3,5], target: 4} output: true
input: {Item Sizes: [1,3,5,4], target: 7} output: true
```

Obviously I can run the array through a loop and add every two numbers together to check if they equal the box size but I need a more efficient way of doing it. The number of calculations grows exponentially for each additional item in the array if we do it like that. For example, given these parameters...

```
input: {Item Sizes: [1,3,5,4], target: 7} output: true
```

it would take 12 calculations to accomplish it this way, if I'm not mistaken (1+3, 1+5, 1+4, 3+1, 3+5, 3+4, etc.). However, if we add one more item to the array, like this...

```
input: {Item Sizes: [1,3,5,4,6], target: 7} output: true
```

it would take 20 calculations. If "n" equals the number of items in the array, the formula would be something like this...

n * (n-1)

One is subtracted from "n" because you can't check the item against itself.
It would take 999000 calculations to check an array of 1000 items.

One way of optimizing is to remove any integers in the array that are larger than the box size and to break out of the function as soon as a match is found.

There must be betters ways of optimizing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the general problem (for unlimited number of items per box) is NP-Hard, and is actually the subset-sum problem.

For your restriction of exactly two items per box, it can be done in a single pass of the data, using a hash table (or an array if the size of the box is not too high), and store the difference from the box's size.

python code:

```
def FindPair(array, box_size):
  s = {} #empty dictionary
  for (i,x)  in enumerate(array):
    if x > box_size:
      continue
    if x in s:
      print 'match for indices:', i, s[x]
      return True
    else:
      s[box_size - x] = i
  return False

print FindPair([1,3,5], 2)
print FindPair([1,1,3,5], 2)
print FindPair([1,3,5], 4)
print FindPair([1,3,5,4], 7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Amit. I'm trying to wrap my head around this...

So we basically store the difference between the item and the box size in a temporary array. Then check each item in the loop for a matching value in the array, adding the next item to the temp array with every iteration. Unless I'm confused, wouldn't that only check each item against previous items that have already been stored in the temp array? I don't see how it would check against the items in the original array that haven't been iterated over yet. Can you please explain?

thanks.

Comment: @LukeJames No. This is done in linear time, since your look up in this additional array is extremely, you know exactly where you should access. If for example your box size is 10, and you see the number 3, you will store it in `aux_array[7]` (10-3=7). Then, if you later see the number `7`, you can now you have already seen `3`, by simply checking if `aux_array[7]` is set.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. This was very helpful.